# Authorize attribute + Validation attributes on inner class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, class-library

Is there a way to put attributes for validation and for security in inner layers?
I want to put the security for example in the API layer.
The api layer is just an injected class to the controller.

the controller invoke the API.

```
api.Join(user);

class UserApi{
    //I want the attribute on a class library.
    [Authorized(Role....)]
    public void Join(User user){}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You could do this by having an API layer invoker class that would check security according to method attributes and then execute method if everything's fine. Similar approach is used in MVC anyway.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, I dont understand you, can you please explain it a little bit deeper? maybe send an example? Thanks

Comment: Check what `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker` class does using Net Reflector, ILSpy or similar tool. Check how it invokes controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

On the class library you can use [PrincipalPermissionAttribute](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&cp=20&gs_id=2b&xhr=t&q=PrincipalPermissionAttribute&pf=p&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=PrincipalPermissionA&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=f7107c3d0079a89d&bpcl=38897761&biw=1600&bih=742).

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "...")]
public void Join(User user){}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it, what about validation attributes?

Comment: Validation attributes would be on your `User` class wouldn't they? And if your controller actions would use that as parameters, properties would get validated automatically by MVC.

Comment: @Joe: But wouldn't this only work with windows authentication so forms auth won't cut it here? Because this attribute checks `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and not `HttpContext.User`...

Comment: if I want to do validation in the API, I need to use the ModelState, which is only existed on the web context

Comment: @RobertKoritnik - no, this is not restricted to Windows authentication.  `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` needs to be set to the same principal as `HttpContext.User`, but if you're using a .NET RoleProvider this is done automatically.  If you're not using `RoleProvider`, you may have to set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` manually, e.g. in Application_AuthorizeRequest.

Comment: @SexyMF - you can manually validate using DataAnnotations attributes.  For example, see the following blog post: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

Comment: @Joe: Ok. Then I will +1 your answer because then this is the **best solution** since it doesn't require any additional API Layer method invoker class. But regarding built-in Asp.net security model (and DB) I never uses it because I find it ridiculously superfluous. I've also never seen several apps sharing the same authentication/authorisation database (what they tried to do). It's true that I manly work on intranet apps so they usually use windows auth anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming), for .net [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999144/aspect-oriented-programing-aop-solutions-for-c-sharp-net-and-their-features) people recommend using [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

Comment: I thought about it, but I think this is really an overkill. .NET does not supports that put of the box?

Comment: @SexyMF: well you're trying to do something that's not provided out of the box by Asp.net MVC anyway... Authorisation filters are provided on controller actions and not on external classes.