# Same catch code for many methods

Tags: c#, .net

I have several C# methods that I want to wrap in a try-catch block. Each function will have the same logic for the catch. Is there an elegant way to add a decorator to each of these functions so they are all wrapped with the same try/catch block? I don't want to add the try/catch block to all of these functions.

Example:

```
public void Function1(){
   try {
     do something
   }catch(Exception e) {
      //a BUNCH of logic that is the same for all functions
   }
}

public void Function2() {
   try {
     do something different
   }catch(Exception e) {
      //a BUNCH of logic that is the same for all functions
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code...

Comment: Why not just try/catch each and send the exception to a common static function?

Comment: use [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)
see for example the following code: http://www.rhyous.com/2012/06/15/aop-implementing-try-catch-in-csharp-with-postsharp/ code is as simple as adding an attribute to the functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999144/aspect-oriented-programing-aop-solutions-for-c-sharp-net-and-their-features

Comment: @JoelEtherton How would I go about doing that, do you have an example?

Comment: Why aren't you letting your excpetions bubble up and get handled (logged) by a global exception handler?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about some functional solution to this? Notice I don't swallow exceptions and use `throw;` statement, that will re-throw exception keeping its original stack trace. Don't silently swallow exceptions - it's considered to be a very bad practice and the debugging code gets horrible.

```
void Main()
{
    WrapFunctionCall( () => DoSomething(5));
    WrapFunctionCall( () => DoSomethingDifferent("tyto", 4));
}

public void DoSomething(int v){ /* logic */}

public void DoSomethingDifferent(string v, int val){ /* another logic */}

public void WrapFunctionCall(Action function) 
{
    try
    {
        function();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         //a BUNCH of logic that is the same for all functions
         throw;
    }
}
```

---

If you need to return some value, the signature for `WrapFunctionCall` method will change

```
void Main()
{
    var result = WrapFunctionCallWithReturn( () => DoSomething(5));
    var differentResult = WrapFunctionCallWithReturn( () => DoSomethingDifferent("tyto", 4));
}

public int DoSomething(int v){ return 0; }

public string DoSomethingDifferent(string v, int val){ return "tyto"; }

public T WrapFunctionCallWithReturn<T>(Func<T> function) 
{
    try
    {
        return function();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //a BUNCH of logic that is the same for all functions
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your code is useful!  I did hit a problem where if all functions (except WrapFunctionCallWithReturn) took ref parameters it would result in an error: "Cannot use ref or out parameter inside an anonymous method...".  We solved it by making a temporary and then assigning it back after the call; is there a way to use this solution with ref or out parameters?

Comment: and with async? which you prefer:

`var result = await WrapFunctionCallWithReturn( () => DoSomething(5));`

`var result = WrapFunctionCallWithReturn( () => await DoSomething(5));`

Comment: i get it:
`var result = await WrapFunctionCallWithReturn( () => DoSomething(5));`
is needed - await must be inside of the try catch

Comment: saved a lot of time!

Comment: Totally irrelevant, but: does "tyto" have any value to you as placeholder string or is it just random letters? (this was an excuse to say 'thank you for this answer!' BTW)

Answer (score 2):

This is Joel Etherton's comment paraphrased as an answer. Note that this isn't the best solution (see Ilya Ivanov's answer for better a solution).
But it's simple and if I read your question correctly it's exactly what you asked for:

```
void errorHandling(Exception e)
{
  // Your BUNCH of logic
}

public void Function1(){
   try {
     do something
   }catch(Exception e) {
      errorHandling(e);
   }
}

public void Function2() {
   try {
     do something different
   }catch(Exception e) {
      errorHandling(e);
   }
}
```