# AOP in .Net MVC outside of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, aop

I  realy like concept of Aspect Oriented Programing and I would like to use it in my aplication for few services. 
Application is Net MVC 4. 
I know about filters, but i would like to use AOP in other classes- outside of controller.
I can't find any resources about this and all i get is filetrs wchich are limited.

Can anyoe point me to some resources how to integrate AOP in MVC4?
Is there any framework easy to integrate with that?

Comment: Unity framework should be good enough

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aspect Oriented Programing (AOP) solutions for C# (.Net) and their features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999144/aspect-oriented-programing-aop-solutions-for-c-sharp-net-and-their-features)

Comment: As I mentioned there is a difference between plain c# appliacatins and ASP.Net. According to support using post# is not reccomended in this case. Don't know what others solutiions are available.

Answer (score 1):

There is some *frameworks* to use `AOP` in `.Net`, but probably most easy to integrate  solution should be [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/), you can also take a look into [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/), but use a completely different approach:

- [compile weaving](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/compiletime-weaving)
- [runtime weaving](http://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/runtime-weaving)

Comment: http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/756-post-sharp-support-for-aspnet-mvc-application
According to this POstSharp is not reccomended.

Comment: @user1208630 - You misunderstood that question.  They're saying that Web Site projects should not use PostSharp, Web Site projects are created with File->New->Web Site.  PostSharp can be used with Web Application projects, which are created with File->New->Project.  MVC sites are Web Application projects, and thus are perfectly fine to use with PostSharp.  The answer refers to Asp.NET, while the question refers to MVC.  The answer does not directly answer the question asked, but is instead answering whether the article he refers to is still valid, not whether MVC can be used.